# How can I save a user selected image (Zbar Scanner) inside apps Documents folder

Tags: core-data, uiimageview, nsfilemanager, xcode4.6, nsdocumentdirectory

So I have 2 views, one of them is a UITableVew where a user can populate cells by adding them. The second view is the information when they add them (Name, date, company and a place to scan a barcode.). Well when they scan that image, they can see the image of what they scanned (Done with Zbar barcode scanner). So the main question is how can I exactly save different images in each different cell that the user adds?

Code:

Zbar:

```
    - (IBAction)cameraButtonTapped:(id)sender
    {
    // Check for camera
    if ([UIImagePickerController               isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == YES) {
        // Create image picker controller
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        // Set source to the camera
        imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        // Delegate is self
        imagePicker.delegate = self;

        // Show image picker
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    }

    }


    - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*)reader
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
    {
    // ADD: get the decode results
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
    [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for(symbol in results)
        // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
        break;

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode data
    resultText.text = symbol.data;

    // EXAMPLE: do something useful with the barcode image
    resultImage.image =
    [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // ADD: dismiss the controller (NB dismiss from the *reader*!)

    [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }

    -(UIView*)CommomOverlay{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

    UIImageView *TopBar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,58)];
    [TopBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
    [view addSubview:TopBar];

    UILabel *Toplabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 9, 300, 30)];
    [Toplabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC light" size:22]];
    [Toplabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [Toplabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [Toplabel setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [Toplabel setNumberOfLines:1];
    [Toplabel setText:@"Turn your device sideways to scan"];
    [TopBar addSubview:Toplabel];

    UIImageView *FrameImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,50,240,370)];
    [FrameImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scanImage.png"]];
    [view addSubview:FrameImg];
    return view;
}



- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped
{
    // ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

    // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];

    // present and release the controller
    reader.cameraOverlayView = [self CommomOverlay];

    [self presentModalViewController: reader
                            animated: YES];

}
```

I did think using core data but i cant find a tutorial anywhere. Then I thought saving it in the apps Documents folder and i think that would be the bes way for me. I am new to this so descriptive code would help :)

Update:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    UIImage *image = resultImage.image;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //convert image into .png format.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@KYRO Receipts Images/Barcode.png", resultImage]]; //add our image to the path
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)
    NSLog(@"image saved");

    if (self.device) {
        // Update existing device
        [self.device setValue:self.nameOfItem.text forKey:@"name"];
        [self.device setValue:self.dateOfPurchase.text forKey:@"date"];
        [self.device setValue:self.companyOfItem.text forKey:@"company"];


    } else {
       // 
        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Receipt" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newDevice setValue:self.nameOfItem.text forKey:@"name"];
        [newDevice setValue:self.dateOfPurchase.text forKey:@"date"];
        [newDevice setValue:self.companyOfItem.text forKey:@"company"];

    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [WTStatusBar setStatusText:@"Saving data..." animated:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setTextStatusProgress3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using Core Data, then depending on the size of the images you could either convert them to NSData and save them directly within Core Data (if they're small) or you can save them within the documents directory and save the file name within Core Data.

Since a full Core Data tutorial is beyond the scope here, I'll just go over saving the image to the documents directory under a unique name. Note that some of the code below was adapted from "[iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_rd_edition_)".

```
// Method to save your image file. Returns the file name for you to save in Core Data or elsewhere.
- (NSString *)saveImage:(UIImage *)image {
    // Generate a unique key to name the image file
    CFUUIDRef newUniqueID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    CFStringRef newUniqueIDString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueID);
    NSString *imgkey = (__bridge NSString *)newUniqueIDString;

    // Get a path for the image file in the documents directory
    NSString *imagePath = [self imagePathForKey:imgkey];

    // Convert the UIImage into NSData and save it to the documents directory
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5);
    [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

    // Clean up
    CFRelease(newUniqueIDString);
    CFRelease(newUniqueID);

    return imgkey;
}

// Method to provide the image path for saving/retrieving the image
- (NSString *)imagePathForKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:key];
}
```

The following method retrieves the image:

```
- (UIImage *)imageForKey:(NSString *)imgkey {
    result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self imagePathForKey:imgkey thumbnail:FALSE]];
    if (!result) {
        // File not found - add code here as needed (to return default image or whatever)
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that if you are planning to display multiple images in the table at the same time, you must be careful to ensure they are small, otherwise you may run into memory issues. In this case you would want to convert them into a thumbnail form for the table view, then display the full size image only in the detail view (how to generate a thumbnail would be a separate question).

Comment: so how would i call this method to save them? i posted a edit with my code for saving